# How to create a complex dictionary with nested dictionary in a list into Pandas DataFrame in streaming data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe out of the complex dictionary here but I am not able to solve the values for last column, if you could please guide me that'd be great!

code -

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

stream= {
    "Outerclass": {
        "Main_ID": "1",
        "SetID": "1041",
        "Version": 2,
        "nestedData": {
            "time": ["5000", "6000", "7000"],
            "values": [{"intValue":1,"value":"intValue"}, {"floatValue":2.5,"value":"floatValue"}, {"stringValue":"abc","value":"stringValue"}]
        }

    } }


s = json_normalize(stream['Outerclass'])
s = s.join(pd.concat([s.pop(x).explode()  for x in ['nestedData.time','nestedData.values']],axis=1))
print(s)
```

Desired Output-

```
Main_ID SetID   Version nestedData.time nestedData.values
1       1041    2       5000            1
1       1041    2       6000            2.5
1       1041    2       7000            abc
```

Actual Output -

```
Main_ID SetID   Version nestedData.time nestedData.values
1       1041    2       5000            {'intValue': 1, 'value': 'intValue'}
1       1041    2       6000            {'floatValue': 2.5, 'value': 'floatValue'}
1       1041    2       7000            {'stringValue': 'abc', 'value': 'stringValue'}
```

Comment: The first key of the `nestedData.values` is different for every row (e.g. `'intValue'`, `floatValue`, `stringValue`), so even if you normalize this json once more, these will all be separate columns. Do you want to essentially disregard what this key is named, and get the associated value regardless of whether it's `intValue`, `floatValue`, etc?

Comment: yes , i need to disregard the first key subtext and want only the associated value

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to extract some of those fields based on a custom logic (not necessarily the classic json normalization), which requires disregarding the first key subtext and essentially getting any value associated with a key that is not `value`, I would suggest the following:

```py
# Almost same as before
s = pd.json_normalize(stream['Outerclass']) #pandas.io.json.json_normalize is actually deprecated
s = s.join(pd.concat(
           [s.pop(x).explode() for x in ['nestedData.time','nestedData.values']], axis=1)
          ).reset_index(drop=True)

def get_value(d):
    """ Extract value from any key that is not 'value' """
    k = [k for k in d.keys() if k != 'value'][0]
    return d.get(k)

s["Values"] = s["nestedData.values"].apply(get_value) # Or you can just replace it
s
```

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
    Main_ID SetID   Version nestedData.time nestedData.values
0   1       1041    2       5000            1
1   1       1041    2       6000            2.5
2   1       1041    2       7000            abc
```

Also, just to note the alternative, using just json normalization:

```
pd.json_normalize(s["nestedData.values"])
```

would result in a table with each possible Key as a column, as expected (but not as desired):

```
    intValue    value       floatValue  stringValue
0   1.0     intValue    NaN         NaN
1   NaN     floatValue  2.5         NaN
2   NaN     stringValue NaN         abc
```